# Will Lightning be implemented on Bitcoin network?

Tags: lightning-network

Lightning cannot currently operate with pruned nodes. I presume without limitation the same applies to SPV nodes. Will Lightning be implemented on the Bitcoin network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning nodes can function in a light client mode by connecting to full nodes who support the new BIP157&158 light client mode. This is supported by LND (the lightning network daemon), and is known as neutrino. On testnet, the lightning faucet operates a neutrino-compatible full node but support will spread and it will eventually become as easy as using SPV currently, with many added benefits over SPV.

Comment: Okay, that's better. I should probably have noted in the question that I was reading the c-lightning implementation readme, not the Lightning specification. Phew! - https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/README.md